# Variables en global python 3

Tags: python

En el programa de una caja registradora, he definido en una función la variable "precio" como global. En otra función la leo y funciona bien, pero a la hora de modificarla, me dice que la variable esta referenciada antes del asignamiento. ¿Cómo lo soluciono, alguna otra función?
**Ejemplo de error: Comparar Print en "Finticket()" y "Devolver()"**

```
print ("**********MAQUINA REGISTRADORA***********")
import time
inventario = [["leche", 1.50, 300], ["lista", 2.35, 400], ["pan", 0.50, 200]]
lista = []



def añprod(prod, prec, cant):#-----------------------funciona
    np = [prod, prec, cant]
    inventario.append(np)
    print ("""Producto Añadido:
    Producto = {}

    Precio = {}
    Cantidad = {}""".format(prod, prec, cant))
    print ("")
    inventario


def ticket(prod, cant):#-----------------------------funciona

    global posprod
    global canttick
    global  precio#--------+++++aquí defino precio+++++---------  
    precio = 0
    i = 0

    canttick = cant
    numprod = len(inventario)

    for a in inventario:
        if prod in a:
            posprod = inventario.index(a)#comprueba si existe el producto

            if cant <= 0:#comprueba si la cantidad es negativa
                print ("Si desea devolver un producto, use la función 'devolver([producto])'")
                break

            if inventario[posprod][2] >= cant:#comprueba el stock
                inventario[posprod][2] -= cant#quita lo pedido del inventario
                print ("En ticket")
                pyc = [prod, cant]

                for a in lista:#comprueba si el producto está repetido 
                    if prod in a:
                        prodrep = lista.index(a)
                        lista[prodrep][1] += cant
                        break
                else:        
                    lista.append(pyc)#añade el producto al ticket

                precio += precio + inventario[posprod][1] * canttick
                break
            else:
                print ("No en Stock")

        else:
            i = i+1

    if i == numprod:
        print ("Producto no encontrado")


def finticket():#------------------------------------funciona

    print ("Productos en lista:")   
    print (lista)
    print ("")
    print ("Precio final: {} €".format (precio))#-------+++++aquí uso precio y funciona++++++++-------------

def devolver(prodev, cantdev):
    print ("Precio: {}".format (precio))#-----++++aquí uso precio y falla+++++-------
    i = 0 
    nprod = len(lista)
    for a in lista:#Comprueba si el producto existe
        if prodev in a:

            if cantdev <= 0:#Comprueba si la cantidad es válida
                print ("Cantidad inválida")
                break

            else:#resta la cantidad indicada
                for prod in inventario:
                    if prodev in prod:
                        if cantdev > a[1]:#comprueba y devuelve el producto 
                            cantinv = cantdev - a[1]
                            op = cantdev - cantinv
                            prod[2] += op

                            precio -= (prod[1] * op)#devuelve el dinero------++++da error++++------

                            print ("Producto devuelto")

                        else:
                            prod[2] += cantdev#devuelve el producto

                            precio -= (prod[1] * cantdev)#devuelve el dinero ----++++da error++++----

                            print("Producto devuelto")

                a[1] -= cantdev

                if a[1] <= 0: #Comprueba y elimina el producto si < 0
                    posdev = lista.index(a)
                    del lista[posdev]
                    break

        else: 
            i += 1

    if i == nprod:
        print ("Producto no encontrado")
```

Comment: Hola Esteban, bienvenido. Sería mejor si nos proporcionaras tu código para poder ayudarte de mejor manera. Te sugiero completes el [tour] del sitio y obtengas tu primera medalla de paso :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un problema que tarde o temprano nos acaba pasando a todos...

Cuando una función hace referencia a una variable *para leerla*, dicha variable se busca primero entre las locales de la función, y si no aparece ahí, se busca entonces entre las globales (aún si no se ha declarado como global dentro de la función).

Sin embargo, si una función hace referencia a una variable *para asignarla*, entonces, a menos que se haya declarado como global dentro de la función, se creará una variable local, aunque exista una global del mismo nombre.

Por ejemplo:

```
v_global = 10

def lee_v_global():
    print(v_global)

def escribe_v_global_y_no_funciona():
    v_global = 20    # Crea en realidad una local
    print(v_global)

print(v_global) # Saldrá 10
lee_v_global()  # Saldrá 10
escribe_v_global_y_no_funciona()  # Saldrá 20
print(v_global) # Sigue siendo 10
```

Para que funcionara correctamente debería ser:

```
def escribe_v_global_bien():
    global v_global    # Declaramos explícitamente la variable
    v_global = 20      # Ahora sí, asignamos la global
```

Y entrando ahora al problema concreto que te aparece a tí ¿qué crees que haría el código siguiente?

```
def funcion_sorpresa():
    # No declaro la variable como global
    print(v_global)   # ¿Escribiría 10?
    v_global = 20     # Y ahora? Está cambiando la global o la local?
```

Pues lo que ocurre es que, antes de ejecutar las funciones python las "compila" (para asegurarse de que no tienen errores sintácticos y para convertirlas a un *bytecode* más rápido de interpretar). Y durante esa fase ve la asignación de la última línea, y por tanto considerará la variable como local, y en los *bytecodes* que genere, hará referencia a esa variable local. Cuando se ponga a ejecutarla, la primera línea que intenta imprimir la variable (que el bytecode trata como local) se encuentra con que todavía esa variable no tiene valor, y ahí sale el infame:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'v_global' referenced before assignment
```

La solución es obviamente declarar esa variable como global dentro de esa función:

```
def funcion_sin_sorpresa():
    global v_global
    print(v_global)   # Escribirá 10
    v_global = 20     # Y modifica la global
```

**Moraleja** Declara siempre como `global` las variables globales que vayas a usar en las funciones, aún si no hace falta (en el caso de que sólo vayas a leerlas y no modificarlas). Nunca hace daño y de hecho el programa quedará más legible.