# ¿Por qué no es necesario pasarle todos los parámetros?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando entender un código que no he escrito yo.

En la definición de la función `calc_R` aparecen cuatro variables:`x, y, xc, yc`. Sin embargo, al llamar a esta función tan sólo le pasan dos variables y funciona correctamente.
¿Por que?

A continuación muestro el código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#  == METHOD 2 ==
# Basic usage of optimize.leastsq
from scipy import optimize as opt
import numpy as np
import f02_graphs as grp

#method_2  = "leastsq"

def calc_R(xc, yc):
    """ Calculate the distance of each 2D points from the center (xc, yc) """
    return np.sqrt((x-xc)**2 + (y-yc)**2)


def f_2(c):
    """ Calculate the algebraic distance between the 2D points and the mean circle centered at c=(xc, yc) """
    Ri = calc_R(*c)
    return Ri - Ri.mean()

# Datos.  
x = [36, 36, 19, 18, 33, 26]
y = [14, 10, 28, 31, 18, 26]
basename = 'arc'

# Coordenadas del baricentro.
x_m = np.mean(x)
y_m = np.mean(y)
barycenter = x_m, y_m
# Aplicamos un algoritmo para aproximar el centro de la circunferencia.
circle_center, ier = opt.leastsq(f_2, barycenter)
xc, yc = circle_center

# Calculamos la distancia al centro de cada par x,y.
R_xy = calc_R(xc, yc)
# Calculamos el promedio de todoas las distancias de R_xy.
R_2 = R_xy.mean()
```

Comment: Porque son variables globales (definidas a nivel de módulo) por lo que la función puede acceder a ellas sin problemas dado que tanto función como variables comparten espacio de nombres (otra cosa es modificar el objeto al que apunta, donde hay que tener en cuenta por ejemplo la mutabilidad del objeto en sí, o reasignar un nuevo objeto al identificador ). De todas formas es preferible pasarlas como argumentos también, facilita la legibilidad y la portabilidad del código y evita errores ocasionados por las "malvadas" variables globales.

Comment: Creía que en Python las variables eran siempre locales y que si querías que fueran globales, tenías que ponerlo de forma explícita.

Comment: @Zhisi Las variables que son asignadas fuera de las funciones son globales. Las que son asignadas dentro de las funciones son locales. Si tienes una variable global, pero le intentas asignar otro valor dentro de una función, eso la convertiría en local. Para evitar eso es para lo que tienes que "declararla" dentro de esa función poniendo la palabra `global` delante. Mírate [esta explicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151774/7123)

Answer (score 1):

Amigo lo que pasa es que las variables `x` y `y` ya están definidas globalmente. El método hace uso de los arreglos de arriba , de ahí toma los valores `x` y `y`.